# sed multiline delete everything before first occurrence of pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I have a multiline string containing some text followed by a JSON, so it has the following format:

```
Some random text
It spans across multiple lines and contains a JSON that does not start at the beginning of the line:
MY_JSON: {
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

I want to extract the JSON **using sed** by removing the text before, so everything until (and including) `MY_JSON:`  (note the trailing space).

My current solution:

```sh
# $str contains above multiline string
$ echo $str | sed '/MY_JSON: /d'
```

I get the following output:

```
Some random text
It spans across multiple lines and contains a JSON that does not start at the beginning of the line:
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

But I want the following output:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

So the idea is to select everything until the first occurrence of `{` and delete it. But that doesn't work. It doesn't delete the first n lines until the line where the pattern matches. It also deletes the whole line instead of just the part until the `{`.

How can I achive best with sed what I want to do?

Comment: Why does it have to be with sed instead of something simpler like awk?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed '1,/MY_JSON:/ {/MY_JSON:/!d; s/^MY_JSON: *//;}' file

{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

**Command Details:**

- `1,/MY_JSON:/`: Match from line 1 to the line that matches `MY_JSON:`
- `{/MY_JSON:/!d; s/^MY_JSON: *//;}`: Delete all lines except last one and then remove `MY_JSON:`  from that line.

Comment: I didn't know the `1,...` part (matching from line 1 to pattern). I think with this information I can simplify @anubhava's solution a bit:
`sed '1,/{/ {/{/!d; s/^[^{]*//;}' file` (so basically doing the same, but using `{` as the pattern instead of `MY_JSON:`

Comment: If `MY_JSON:` is marker for start of JSON block then it is better to use that.

Comment: why is that better?

Comment: A stand alone `{` can be part of any other text as well but `MY_JSON:` is unlikely

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^[a-zA-Z][^{]*//;/^$/d' input_file
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If file has only one json structure**

Input

```
It spans across multiple lines and contains a JSON that does not start at the beginning of the line:
MY_JSON: {
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

```
sed '1h;1!H;${;g;s/^[^:]*:[^{]*\({.*}\).*/\1/p;}' -n
```

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

**If file has multiple json structures**

Input

```
Some random text
It spans across multiple lines and contains a JSON that does not start at the beginning of the line:
MY_JSON: {
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
some
My: {
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}

Some random text
It spans across multiple lines and contains a JSON that does not start at the beginning of the line:
MY_JSON: {
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

```
sed '/^[^{]*{/,/^}/!d;s/^[^{]*{/{/g'
```

OR

```
sed '1h;1!H;${;g;s/^[^:]*:[^{]*\({.*}\).*/\1/;p}' -n | sed -n '/^[^{]*{/,/^}/{;p}' | sed 's/^[^{]*{/{/g'
```

In above command remove anything after ; to retain MY_JSON like titles

Output

```
{
  "foo": [
{
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
{
  "foo": [
{
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
{
  "foo": [
{
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

If alternative of sed are plausible:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460087/extract-json-from-a-text-file-with-arbitrary-text
has good solution with grep

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution on the positive approach.

Instead of removing data, extract data from the file.

```
$ sed --quiet '/MY_JSON:/,$  {s/^MY_JSON: //;p}' input.1.txt
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz",
     (...) // more content here
    }
   ]
}
```

#### Explanation

`--quiet` Prevent print duplication.

`/MY_JSON:/,$` Range of text from line matching regexp /MY_JSON:/ to last line. Denoted as $

`{...}` sed execution list on each line in the range.

`s/^MY_JSON: //; p` Substitute  "MY_JSON: " with "" than print each line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky enough to have the JSON start at the beginning of its own line, and start with a `{` on its own line, like so:

```bash
echo 'MY_JSON:
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "baz"
    }
  ]
}' > file.notquitejson
```

Then you can extract just the json like this:

```bash
{ echo '{'; cat file.notquitejson | sed '1,/^{/d' } > file.json
```

Explanation:

- `{} > file.json` run some stuff and put its output in a file
- `{ echo '{' } > file.json` start that file with a `{`
- `cat file.notquitejson | sed '1,/^{/d'` delete from lines 1 until **and including** the fist time that `{` starts a line
- `{ echo '{'; cat file.notquitejson | sed '1,/^{/d' } > file.json` start the file with a `{` and end the file with everything after the first `{`